# Disallow Soft deleted User to log in using Auth in laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, soft-delete

I have soft deleted User and it worked fine. When I list users list it does not show deleted user means it worked well. I also checked it in database table.The deleted_at field is created when I soft delete it. The problem is that When I logging in with the soft deleted users credential it is allowing me. I dont want to allow soft deleted User to be logged in. I am using Auth for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code provided on the Laravel documentation, where you would replace active => 1 with deleted_at => null

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1)))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Comment: Thanks..! that solved my problem. The only thing required is I have to add a field `active` in table and every time when I soft delete the user I updated active field to 0.

Comment: Just came across this and helped solve my issue, one comment to OP tho, if you fully read the answer instead of just copy/paste code you will have seen that there is no need to create an active field, and the answer includes the changes you need to make.

Comment: it is not working, in fact the definition of the function is public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)